# How do I navigate to the next file in the visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to go to the next file without a mouse click?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the runCommands command to focus the current file, move the focus and to open the selection.

```
{
    "key": "alt+cmd+up",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
        "list.focusUp",
        "list.select"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+down",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
        "list.focusDown",
        "list.select"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold Ctrl and press Tab to view a list of all files open in an editor group. To open one of these files, use Tab again to pick the file you want to navigate to, then release Ctrl to open it. Alternatively, you can use Ctrl+Alt+- and Ctrl+Shift+- to navigate between files and edit locations.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved